# I cant figure out what is causing the output problem or how to fix it (C++)

Tags: c++

My goal here is to output:

1. the latest books where the printing time is 2022
2. the books with the type "childrensbook"
3. IT book with the highest price

But, as shown in the code below, I can't seem to figure out what is causing my output problem.

After I run the program and give the information needed, for example:

```
bookname : flower
bookISBN : 12
book printingtime : 2022
bookprice 500
booktype : childrensbook
```

I get a list with symbols that I can't show in here unfortunately, because of the site's policies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Books
{
    protected:
        char name[25];
        int ISBN;
        int printingtime;
        double price;
        char type[25];
        double high_price = 0.0;
    public:
                
        void getBookdetails()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            {
                cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"name"<<"  ";
                cin >> name;
                cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"ISBN"<<"  ";
                cin >> ISBN;
                cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"printingtime"<<"  ";
                cin >> printingtime;
                cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"price"<<"  ";
                cin >> price;
                cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"type"<<"  ";
                cin >> type;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        
        virtual void print()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            {
                cout <<"book "<<(i+1)<<" name: "<< name << endl;
                cout <<"book "<<(i+1)<<" ISBN: "<< ISBN << endl;
                cout <<"book "<<(i+1)<<" printingtime: "<< printingtime << endl;
                cout <<"book "<<(i+1)<<" price: "<< price << endl;
                cout <<"book "<<(i+1)<<" type: "<< type << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
};

class latestBooks:public Books
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout <<"the latest books are:"<< endl;
            Books :: print();
        }
};

class childrensBooks :public Books
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout <<"the childrens books are:"<< endl;
            Books :: print();
        }
};

class ITBooks:public Books
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout <<"the IT books with hightest price are:"<< endl;
            Books :: print();
            cout << high_price << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int printingtime{};
    double price=0;
    char type[25];
    const int size=2;
    char books[size]={};
    double high_price = 0.0;
    int hp=0;
    Books b;
    b.getBookdetails();
    
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(printingtime = 2022)
        {
            latestBooks B1;
            B1.print();
        }else 
            if(type == ("childrensbook"))
            {
                childrensBooks B2;
                B2.print();
            }else
                if(price >= high_price)
                {
                    price = high_price;
                    hp++;
                    ITBooks B3;
                    B3.print();
                }
    }
    cout <<"the IT books with hightest price are  "<< hp << "  at the price of " << high_price << endl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are headed in a bad direction by trying to apply inheritance. The only difference between a latest book and every other book is an arbitrary threshold in a variable. As soon as the book crosses this threshold, it does not suddenly become a new type, at least not without an excessive and pointless amount of work. What you really want to do is either sort the list of books and report on the section of the list that's before the the threshold or search through an unsorted list and report on every book newer than the threshold.

Comment: Inheritance for a children's book makes a bit more sense, but unless it has significant behavioural changes from a regular book, I would just have a type member variable and set that type to `childrens_book` or `young_adult` or `romance` or whatever.

Comment: You probably should start with renaming `class Books` to `class Book`. Meditate over this for a couple of moments, then rewrite your methods to reflect the fact that they deal with **one** book.

Answer (score 3):

So you have a misunderstanding about how methods work. You have a Book class, that's good. But in your Book class you are trying to write methods for an array of books. The Book class methods are for **one book only**, not for an array of books. You have to call the book's methods once for each book that you want to enter or print. Here's how it works (I'll do the `getBookdetails` method only, you can make the same fix for `print`).

```
class Book
{
    ...
    void getBookdetails(int i)
    {
        cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"name"<<"  ";
        cin >> name;
        cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"ISBN"<<"  ";
        cin >> ISBN;
        cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"printingtime"<<"  ";
        cin >> printingtime;
        cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"price"<<"  ";
        cin >> price;
        cout <<"enter book"<<(i+1)<<"type"<<"  ";
        cin >> type;
        cout << endl;
    }
    ...
};

int main()
{
    ...
    Book books[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        books[i].getBookdetails(i);
    ...
}
```

Do you see? The `getBookdetails` method gets the details for one book, and you have an array of books in main and a loop in that calls the method once for each book you have. There is no loop in `getBookdetails`.

When you write classes you have to think what the class represents. You could write a class that represents one book, or you could write a class that represents an array of books. But whichever option you pick you have to be **consistent**. A book is not the same thing as an array of books.

In this case, without a doubt the best approach is to write your class a representing a single book and then have an array of those books in main.

Plus I agree with the other commenters, unless you've been specifically told you must use inheritance I would stay away from it. Any even if you do end up using it, you need to get the basics right first. So for now at least, delete all the inheritance stuff.